# JQuery function or functions for dates

Tags: jquery-validate

I building a custom user control in asp.net where the user can enter in a date. I am already using a JQuery function that puts in a date mask in the format of dd/mm/yyyy, but I am unable to find another JQuery function(s) or one that combines all my needs.

What I am also looking for is:

1) To validate whether the date is really a date, i.e. not 31/13/2010 or anything along those lines.

2) Where I can check to see whether a date is in the past or in future based upon a configuration entry in the application.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head, but you could use JavaScript's `Date` object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

1) You could use one of the following

```
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Then verify that the date components are the same as entered. If you set the month to 50, it will take the year, and go 50 months forward... which seems odd, but... Just have to verify the information is what you entered. The months start at 0 for January, so when checking, be aware of that.

2) There's probably a lot of ways to do this check, but a quick thought on it is

```
var t = d.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
```

If t is positive, it's in the future, if it's negative it's in the past.
The `new Date()` creates a date object with the current time.

You could also use the jQuery UI DatePicker. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
I haven't checking into the exact functionality it has that might fit your requirement, but it is another resource to check into.

HTH